Lucas number of the type $3k^2$
We seek to find all integer solutions to the equation $L_n = 3k^2$, where $L_n$ is the $n$-th Lucas number. We can see that $L_3$ satisfies this condition. Are there any other such integers $n$? Moreover, is there a method to prove whether other solutions exist?
If we look into the paper by Cohn, J. H. E., Lucas and Fibonacci numbers and some diophantine equations, Proc. Glasg. Math. Assoc. 7, 24-28 (1965). ZBL0127.01902.,
we can say that $3$ divides $L_n$ if and only if $n \equiv 2 (mod\ 4)$. Therefore $2$ divides $n$. We proved that if $L_n=3k^2$ then, $k$ has to be odd. If possible, suppose $k$ is even. Then $2 \mid L_n$ which will imply $3 \not \mid n$ (by identity 6 of the above cited paper). Again by identity (10) of the above paper, we deduce that $L_n \equiv 3\ (mod\ 4)$, which implies $L_n$ is an odd number, which is a contradiction. Therefore if $L_n=3k^2$, then $k$ must be odd, i.e., $L_n$ must be odd. After this, I am unable to proceed further.
Thank you in advance.

See here for results. It seems that Cohen has already proved, that the only Lucas squares are $1$ and $4$, and that the only Lucas number of the form $2k^2$ is $L_6=18$. I suspect that the case $3k^2$ is still open.

I found this paper. It seems that $L_3$ is the only Lucas number of the form $3k^2$, if I understand correctly. It is proved for generalised Lucas numbers. The ordinary case is $P=Q=1$.

@DietrichBurde Thank you for your valuable feedback. I will look into the paper.
